# Заменить слова с сохранением регистра

Tags: javascript, jquery, регулярные-выражения

Есть такой код:

```
var textt = "Объект первый, объект второй, ОБЪЕКТ третий";
textt.replace(/объект/gi,"вещь");
```

Получается ответ:

```
вещь первый, вещь второй, вещь третий
```

Как сделать так, чтобы получился ответ:

```
Вещь первый, вещь второй, ВЕЩЬ третий
```

Т.е. регистр должен быть таким, как было до замены

Comment: `textt.replace(/объект/g,"вещь");
textt.replace(/ОБЪЕКТ/g,"ВЕЩЬ");`

Comment: @splash58 xdxdxd

Comment: А если `ОбъЕКт`, то `вещь` какая?

Comment: Для "ВЕЩЬ" и "вещь" решение есть, но что делать с "вЕЩь" непонятно.

Answer (score 1):

Ну это скорее так, ради забавы.

```js
const textt1 = "Объект первый, объект второй, ОБЪЕКТ третий";
const textt2 = "ОБъЕкт первый, оБЪект второй, ОБЪЕКТ третий";

const upOrLow = (l, sl) => l ? l === l.toUpperCase() ? sl.toUpperCase() : sl.toLowerCase() : sl;
const replaceObject = (str, target, replacer) => str.replace(new RegExp(target, "gi"), ($0) => replacer.split('').map((e, i) => upOrLow($0[i], e)).join(""));


console.log(replaceObject(textt1, 'Объект', 'вещь'));
console.log(replaceObject(textt2, 'Объект', 'вещь'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Получилось написать такую программу:

```
var textt = "Объект первый, объект второй, ОБЪЕКТ третий";

function ucfirst(str){return str.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + str.slice(1);}

textt.replace(/объект/gi,function($0){ zamena = "вещь"; if($0 === $0.toUpperCase()){zamena = zamena.toUpperCase();}else if($0 === ucfirst($0)){zamena = ucfirst(zamena);}else{zamena = zamena.toLowerCase();} return zamena;});
```

Добавляем функцию в `replace()`. Там уже с помощью конструкции `if` пишем наши условия. В данном случае мы сравниваем регистры букв или строк (большой, маленький и первая большая буква). Для последнего потребовалась отдельная функция: `function ucfirst(str){return str.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + str.slice(1);}`
Таким образом получили то, что хотели:

```
Вещь первый, вещь второй, ВЕЩЬ третий
```

Всем спасибо!